# Error using nested for loop in Matlab to extract results from data structure. Why?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

```
function result = results() 
i = [1,5];
    for repeats = 1:1:7
        ratio_counter = 1;
        for ratio = i
            [a,~] = main(75,100,ratio,1000);
            output(repeats) = a.food;
            tabled_output(ratio_counter,repeats) = output
            ratio_counter = ratio_counter + 1;
        end
    end
    result = tabled_output
end
```

Attempting to get 7 repeat sets of results but receiving the following error:

```
Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton
    subscripts

Error in results (line 16)
            tabled_output(ratio_counter,repeats) = output
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the [debugger](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html)! The error means that the size of `tabled_output(ratio_counter,repeats)` and `output` does not match. Perhaps you mean: `tabled_output(ratio_counter,repeats) = output(repeats);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general tip, you can use the matlab GUI interface to go line-by-line through code to debug stuff like this. (click on the dash next to a line of code to set a breakpoint).

Your specific problem looks to be

```
output(repeats) = a.food;
```

this creates `output(1)` (same dimensions as a.food), then appends `output(2)` in the next loop, creating some larger matrix object.

the consequence of this expanding `output` object is that

```
tabled_output(ratio_counter,repeats) = output
```

becomes nonsense.  The LHS needs an object of particular size, you feed it a much larger object.

This can be fixed by

```
tabled_output(ratio_counter,repeats) = output(repeats);
```

or by

```
output = a.food;
```

depending on your overall requirements.  The latter is more memory efficient